# JQuery click event to add or remove table rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have a table that has plus or minus glyph-icons at the top that allow the user to add or subtract rows. The code I have works but if the user clicks the minus button too many times it will eat the whole table.

What I have tried is to add an unique ID tag to the rows I add and only delete the TRs with the ID but if 2 rows are added and the minus is pressed both rows will be deleted at once, I only want to delete one row at a time. Note: the code below does not reflect this attempt.

Glyphicons:

```
<div class="well" style="margin-bottom:0px;" id="addrow">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" id="add"></span>
  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus" id="minus"></span>
```

Table:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped" style="margin-bottom:0px;" id="myTable">
    <tr>
      <td>Customer Master #</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" ></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#addrow").on("click", "span#add", function(){
      var tablerow = '<tr><td><input type="text" class="form-control" ></td></tr>'
      $("#myTable tr:last").after(tablerow);
    })
    $("#addrow").on("click", "span#minus", function(){
      $('#myTable tr:last').remove();
    } )
  });
```

Comment: Use classes for that instead of IDs, IDs are supposed to be unique

Comment: You are correct but no matter which I use the same result will happen.

Comment: I wasnt able to reproduce your error...please update the fiddle with your problematic code http://jsfiddle.net/GRUFA/

Comment: [**This**](http://jfnoel.com/SO/dynamic_table/admin.html) could probably help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added an if statement to only allow a row to be taken out if the table has 3 or more rows. This preserves the last two rows that I always want to be on the page.

```
if ($('#myTable tr').length > 2)
```

This seemed to solve the problem.

Full code:

```
 $("#addrow").on("click", "span#minus", function(){
      if ($('#myTable tr').length > 2) {
      $('#myTable tr:last').remove();
    };
    } )
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure 100% you want changed with your code, but here is a fiddle which adds or removes - but will not remove the first row (won't eat the whole table).

http://jsfiddle.net/HR5se/

```
$('#myTable tr .form-control').size()
```

Will give you how many data (input) rows there are. In this fiddle, I check to see if there's greater than one data row, and if not, the remove doesn't happen.

Note: I turned your glyphs into "+" and "-" text so I could see them here.

Comment: This is a step in the right direction. In my code there are a lot more columns. I simplified it for the question. I would rather not make my selections based on .form-control.

Comment: @SteveW. Are you able to adapt this towards your real code? The idea is to uniquely identify your input rows with a class, then .count() that class to ensure that the delete only works if there are at least 2 of them.

Answer (score 0):

See if changing the `onclick` event to `mouseup` has any effect. I had a similar problem a while back.